# ASP MVC, how to get controller which called RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I have 2 controllers.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                // do some stuff if controller before was ServiceController
                    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);           

            }

    public ActionResult Index()
            {            
                    return View();
            }
}
```

and `ServiceController` with

```
public ActionResult Confirm()
            { return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");}
```

How can I know in HomeController if action was called by RedirectToAction from Service controller? Is there any way?
(I don't want to use cookies or send it in parameters, because I have lots of RedirectToAction in whole controller and I want to apply it globally for controller)

Answer (score 1):

RedirectToAction is actually part of the controller itself and not an actionresult so you could override it and populate the tempdata you need from there:

```
protected override RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
{
    TempData["RedirectedFromAction"] = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    TempData["RedirectedFromController"] = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    return base.RedirectToAction(actionName, controllerName, routeValues);
}
```

Then you can check filterContext.Controller.TempData["RedirectedFromController"] is ServiceController or whatever. If you need this in more than one spot, you can create a BaseController.

Comment: UrlReferrer is null in OnActionExecuting method... TempData is not what I want because I would need to do it in every method with redirection

Comment: Request.ServerVariables don't contain http_referrer

Comment: You can use the tempdata idea via a filter or custom actionresult that just sets the tempdata value and then redirects as it normally would but youd still have to replace it in all the controllers.

Comment: @Maarty Check the edit. Turns out the redirect was done through a controller method and not an actionresult so something like that should work